# Horizontal and Vertical scrolling UITableViews

Tags: ios, uitableview, horizontalscrollview

I am trying to implement a horizontal scrolling UITableView on the iPad, just like the Raombi app, in which the left panel sticks to its own place when scrolling horizontally. Moreover the UITableView is based on a columnar approach so it should scroll seamlessly together.

I have no idea how to start in order to fulfil these requirements.

Here is the screenshot of the desired functionality.
[image]

Comment: You should use UICollectionView instead of UiTableView.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Here i have written solution for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334978/stuck-understanding-how-to-create-a-table-with-multiple-columns-in-ios-swift/40569976#40569976

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad just rotate your table to 90 degree and load cells by rotating every cells to -90 degree. Consider your first column as table header and rest every column as table cell.
Go through below.Add this in viewDidLoad

```
self.tblDetail.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
```

And below lines in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
if(!cell){
    UIViewController *controller=[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:CellIdentifier bundle:nil];
    cell=(MyCustomCell *)controller.view;
    cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
}
```

Apart from that design your header and cell in different nib files. For header just do as below:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 

{
    MyHeaderView *myView = //Your view instantiation code
    myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
    return myView;
}
```

Comment: I am not aware of this approach. Can u please provide some code to show this approach of yours.Thanks for responding quickly

Answer (score -1):

I think this view is too complex to show in the one screen and generate it.
Since the iphone size is too less to display above view easily. Still if the following links  useful to you  please use it and get back to me.

I hope the following links are useful to you.

1)
http://code4app.net/ios/Multiple-Columns-TableView/4f901ef306f6e7123a000000
2)
http://code4app.net/ios/XCMultiSortTableView/520881e56803fa991f000000

3)
http://code4app.net/ios/RATreeView/524e2f896803fa6e31000001

4) 
http://code4app.net/ios/Multiple-columns-Table/51e4dd116803fa1026000000

5) 
http://code4app.net/ios/Static-column-table/50fe649d6803fa7b65000001

Comment: I want it for iPad only!

Comment: yeh, you can do it for iPad only provided you need to arrange the tableview frame as per your need for portrait as well as landscape mode. Hope the above link code can be modified and can be useful to you.

Comment: You can just create un custom UITableViewCell with the layout and style you want! This will be easier and will consume less resources.

Comment: This does nothing to answer question. It's a collection of links.

Comment: sorry sir, but i am trying to helping Shikhar and understanding his actual requirement. since i am also new for this scenario so interested to involve into it and trying learning new stuff. Hope i am not misguiding atleast.

Comment: Not misguiding. Answers here should be concrete attempts to answer a question. A collection of related links isn't an answer and becomes stale. But welcome to SO :-)

Comment: yeh , you are right and glad to be here thanking you.