# Stuck understanding how to create a table with multiple columns in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I've spent the better half of the day so far researching and trying to understand how to make a table with multiple columns. Embarrassingly, I am still quite new to Swift and programming in general  so a lot of the stuff I've read and found aren't helping me too much.

I have basically found exactly what I want to create with this gentleman's blo: 
  http://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/uicollectionview-using-horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling-sticky-rows-and-columns

However, even with his Github I'm still confused. It seems as if he did not use Storyboard at all (and for my project I've been using storyboard a lot). Am I correct in assuming this?

What I have so far is a UICollectionView embedded in a navigation controller. From here, I have created a new cocoa touch class file subclassed in the CollectionView. But from here is where I'm not entirely sure where to go.

If I can have some direction as to where to go from here or how to properly set it up that would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: SO is not a great site for "show me how to do <complex task>" type questions. It's more suited to"here is my code, I'm having a problem with this line" type questions. You should do more research, come up with an approach, and then post questions about your propose approach.

Comment: I think it's a good question that other people may have in the future, but I'd recommend posting your current UICollectionView code as a starting point then describing what about your current code isn't working. (Similar to what Duncan said.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One approach is to use a custom cell in a tableviewcontroller. Your story board consists of a table in which the cell is a custom cell with UILabels for columns laid out next to each other (with properly defined constraints).

Example code for the controllers looks like:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 3
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell
        cell.column1.text = "1" // fill in your value for column 1 (e.g. from an array)
        cell.column2.text = "2" // fill in your value for column 2

        return cell
    }

}
```

and:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var column1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var column2: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: Syed, thank you for your reply. I notice that you have written under the class tableViewController cell.column1.text ="1" and cell.column2.text = "2". My question is do I declare the variables column1 and column2 in this file class?

Comment: No. You declare it in the declaration of the class sub-classed from UITableViewCell as IBOutlets (see the second controller code). Typically you (1) you create the labels for column1 and column2 in the Storyboard in the custom cell. (2) create a new file (which I called TableViewCell sub-classed to UITableViewCell) (3) make it the file in the secondary editor (4) control-drag from the labels in the Storyboard to the file and name the IBOutlets column1 and column2 respectively.

Comment: Hi Syed, do you know how I would enter the values in the column1 and column2 so that each row doesn't display the same value? For example , in the dropbox files you provided (thanks so much!) it will display in column1 the value "1" repeatedly for the amount of rows I return. I tried to change some things such as putting them in an array but i get an error...i must be doing something wrong. I tried: cell.column1.[Double] = [1,2,3]

Comment: I modified the code to read from an array. There are numerous ways to implement this depending on your need. In the example, I used a 2-index array. A double for each column. If you have a more complicated calculation you can use a function to which you pass a row as an argument and have the function return 2 outputs - one for each column. I also realized that in the auto-layout you need to use the  right constraints to get the right widths for the columns. (I did not do it properly) . Hope this helps

Comment: Syed, I get the error UITableViewCell is not convertible to 'TableViewCell';did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast? But even if I do that, and syntactically it works, when you actually execute line, you get the error Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x109132540) to 'myApp.TableViewCell' (0x106bd44d0). Do you have any idea why that might happen? Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Xcode and swift are you using. I will try it out and see if I can trace the problem.

Comment: Please see my answer on an alternate approach using stack view. It feel it is a lot more flexible

Answer (score 14):

***IOS 10, XCode 8, Swift 3.0***

*I found an awesome [tutorial](https://www.credera.com/blog/mobile-applications-and-web/building-a-multi-directional-uicollectionview-in-swift/) on this. thanks to **Kyle Andrews***

*I created a vertical table which can be scrollable on both directions by subclassing UICollectionViewLayout. Below is the code.*

```
 class CustomLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

    let CELL_HEIGHT: CGFloat = 50
    let CELL_WIDTH: CGFloat = 180


    var cellAttributesDictionary = Dictionary<IndexPath, UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes>()
    var contentSize = CGSize.zero

    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        get {
            return contentSize
        }
    }

    var dataSourceDidUpdate = true

    override func prepare() {

        let STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
        let NAV_BAR_HEIGHT = UINavigationController().navigationBar.frame.size.height

        collectionView?.bounces = false

        if !dataSourceDidUpdate {

            let yOffSet = collectionView!.contentOffset.y

            for section in 0 ..< collectionView!.numberOfSections {
                if section == 0 {
                    for item in 0 ..< collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: section) {
                        let cellIndexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: section)
                        if let attrs = cellAttributesDictionary[cellIndexPath] {
                            var frame = attrs.frame
                            frame.origin.y = yOffSet + STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT + NAV_BAR_HEIGHT
                            attrs.frame = frame
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
           return
        }

        dataSourceDidUpdate = false

        for section in 0 ..< collectionView!.numberOfSections {
            for item in 0 ..< collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: section) {
                let cellIndexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: section)
                let xPos = CGFloat(item) * CELL_WIDTH
                let yPos = CGFloat(section) * CELL_HEIGHT

                let cellAttributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: cellIndexPath)
                cellAttributes.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: CELL_WIDTH, height: CELL_HEIGHT)

                // Determine zIndex based on cell type.
                if section == 0 && item == 0 {
                    cellAttributes.zIndex = 4
                } else if section == 0 {
                    cellAttributes.zIndex = 3
                } else if item == 0 {
                    cellAttributes.zIndex = 2
                } else {
                    cellAttributes.zIndex = 1
                }

                cellAttributesDictionary[cellIndexPath] = cellAttributes

            }
        }

        let contentWidth = CGFloat(collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)) * CELL_WIDTH
        let contentHeight = CGFloat(collectionView!.numberOfSections) * CELL_HEIGHT
        contentSize = CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        var attributesInRect = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        for cellAttrs in cellAttributesDictionary.values {
            if rect.intersects(cellAttrs.frame) {
                attributesInRect.append(cellAttrs)
            }
        }

        return attributesInRect
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return cellAttributesDictionary[indexPath]
    }

    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

*Below is my CollectionViewController Code.*

```
    import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class VerticalCVC: UICollectionViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView?.isScrollEnabled = true
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        return 20
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
            cell.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white


        } else {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            cell.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        }

        cell.titleLabel.text = "section: \(indexPath.section) && row: \(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }
}
```

*To force CollectionView to use Custom Layout instead of UICollectionViwFlowLayout check below image.*

[image]

***Result:***

*Portrait mode*

[image]

*landscape mode*

[image]

Comment: your collection view work perfact for me until i added search functionality to it...what should i do if i want to allow searching of data? With this code it always throw exception on data reloading

Comment: how to fix cell height based on label text size inside collection view in this case?

Comment: That tutorial is incredibly well done and comes at it from such a simple approach

Comment: How to set different column width?

Answer (score -1):

In IB I set up a tableview and added a stackview in the content view (can be done programmatically). The labels are setup programmatically since it allows me to set the width of each column as a fraction of the cell width. Also, I acknowledge that some of the calculations inside the table view cellForRow method should be moved out.

```
 import UIKit

class tableViewController: UITableViewController {
var firstTime = true
var width = CGFloat(0.0)
var height = CGFloat(0.0)
var cellRect = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)

let colors:[UIColor] = [
    UIColor.greenColor(),
    UIColor.yellowColor(),
    UIColor.lightGrayColor(),
    UIColor.blueColor(),
    UIColor.cyanColor()
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
// workaround to get the cell width 
    cellRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width ,44);
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

var cellWidth = CGFloat(0.0)
var cellHeight = CGFloat(0.0)
let widths = [0.2,0.3,0.3,0.2]
let labels = ["0","1","2","3"]

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let v = cell.contentView.subviews[0] // points to stack view
        // Note: using w = v.frame.width picks up the width assigned by xCode.
        cellWidth = cellRect.width-20.0 // work around to get a right width
        cellHeight = cellRect.height

        var x:CGFloat = 0.0
        for i in 0 ..< labels.count {
            let wl = cellWidth * CGFloat(widths[i])
            let lFrame = CGRect(origin:CGPoint(x: x,y: 0),size: CGSize(width:wl,height: cellHeight))
            let label = UILabel(frame: lFrame)
            label.textAlignment = .Center
            label.text = labels[i]
            v.addSubview(label)
            x = x + wl
            print("i = ",i,v.subviews[i])
            v.subviews[i].backgroundColor = colors[i]
        }


    return cell
}


}
```